# Isomorphic TypeScript / require

Tags: typescript

I have 4 files

**Settings.ts**

```js
type sayType = () => string;

export interface SettingsModule {
    sayEnv: sayType;
}
```

**settings.node.ts**

```js
import { SettingsModule } from '@/core/persistant/Settings';

export const mod: SettingsModule = {
    sayEnv: sayInternalEnv,
};

function sayInternalEnv(): string {
    return 'Node';
}
```

**settings.browser.ts**

```js
import { SettingsModule } from '@/core/persistant/Settings';

export const mod: SettingsModule = {
    sayEnv: sayInternalEnv,
};

function sayInternalEnv(): string {
    return 'Browser';
}
```

**settings.impl.ts**

```js
import { SettingsModule } from '@/core/persistant/Settings';

let settingsModule: SettingsModule;

if (window.indexedDB) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-var-requires
    const m = require('./settings.browser') as { mod: SettingsModule };
    settingsModule = m.mod;
} else {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-var-requires
    const m = require('./settings.node') as { mod: SettingsModule };
    settingsModule = m.mod;
}

export const sayEnv = settingsModule.sayEnv;
```

The whole thing works like a charm but my question is it really safe to use `require` this way?

I mean - it works fine for such small files but is `require` always synchronous? Can I be sure that 'sayEnv' is always set?

Comment: yes, this will work always, what specific concern do you have?

Comment: if you don't want to rewrite the whole type of the module, in newer versions of ts you can use `require('./settings.node') as typeof import('./settings.node')`;

Comment: @netchkin Thanks - I'm rather new to TS and I wasn't sure what's going to happen if settings.browser.ts has 100k and settings.node.ts has 500k. I was also a bit surprised that I couldn't find very much about conditional AND typesafe loading. Another thing that surprised me was how easy it was to implement. I thought I must be wrong in a way...

Comment: about that: https://bytearcher.com/articles/loading_modules_with_require/
It does not mention typescript though. However, your code gets transpiled into javascript, so browser knows nothing about your types